# how to export function and use it as middleware node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

in my `middleware` folder, I have a file called `auth.js`.

In this file, I have this function:

```
function authCheck () {
      if (req.session.loggedin) {

          return;

      } else {

          req.session.destory();
          res.redirect('/login')

     }

}
```

I need to export it, and then use it in my other files, so then I would need to import it inside of my root directory `app.js` file, and my `routes` folder, those `js` files there.

I basically want to do this:

```
app.get('/index', authCheck, (req, res) => {

 .....
}
```

how do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `app.use` assuming you're using expressjs and use `next()` to continue the execution

*auth.js*

```
function authCheck (req, res, next) {
      if (req.session.loggedin) {

          next();

      } else {

          req.session.destory();
          res.redirect('/login')

     }

}
module.exports = { authCheck }
```

*app.js*

```
const {authCheck} = require('./auth.js');

app.use(authCheck)
app.get('/index', (req, res) => {

 .....
}
```

Comment: but does the function have to be defined in the `app.js` file, or can it be defined in my middleware folder still?

Comment: you can define it whereever you want, but if its elsewhere than you have to require it

Comment: that seemed to work, however, it says `next()` is undefined?

Comment: nvm that was a stupid question, forgot to define next in my function. This way worked like a charm, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Node modules is what you're looking for.

Here's an example from the nodejs documentation.

Export a function from `addTwo.mjs`

```js
// addTwo.mjs
function addTwo(num) {
  return num + 2;
}

export { addTwo };
```

Import and use the exported function in `app.mjs`

```js
// app.mjs
import { addTwo } from './addTwo.mjs';

// Prints: 6
console.log(addTwo(4));
```

Note that the file extension`.mjs` is used to specify that you're using es6 modules.
Read more here.

https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_introduction

Comment: this way could work as well. I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

You can create a middleware like auth.js file in it and add auth code in it like below:

```
module.exports = {
    authCheck: (req, res, next) => {
   }
}
```

And import that file in your route folder and use it like below:

```
const auth = require('../middlewares/auth')

router.post("/", auth.authCheck, (req, res, next) => {
      
});
```